# Trouble saving from console due to current_user NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, console

I have been trying to save some information via the console. I am able to update the entry but when I go ahead and try saving it, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `current_user' for nil:NilClass
```

My initial reaction was that I need to be "logged in" to a user but the console should not require this (unless I'm mistaken). I am currently on my local server and still running into this issue. I was able to complete this type of action some time ago but now it is not allowing me. This is a large issue since I need to use the console to manually update entries for admin and/or troubleshooting purposes.

Just to provide an example with my current schema (may or may not be helpful/relevant):

```
2.1.1 :022 > task = Task.find(16)
  Task Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "tasks".* FROM "tasks"  WHERE "tasks"."id" = ?  ORDER BY importance DESC, priority DESC, duedate, updated_at LIMIT 1  [["id", 16]]
 => #<Task id: 16, description: "new tasks", done: false, project_id: 8, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, due: nil, started: true, active: nil, repeat: nil, time_limit: nil, priority: nil, assignee: "", creator: "sally@google.com", started_at: nil, completed_at: nil, paused_at: nil, resumed_at: nil, time_spent: nil, accepted: nil, duedate: nil, duetime: nil, repeat_time: nil, repeat_day: nil, repeat_date: nil, repeat_ordinal: nil, importance: ""> 
2.1.1 :023 > task.started_at = DateTime.now
 => Mon, 14 Jul 2014 12:02:47 -0700 
2.1.1 :024 > task.save
   (0.8ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (1.3ms)  UPDATE "tasks" SET "started_at" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "tasks"."id" = 16  [["started_at", "2014-07-14 12:02:47.458736"], ["updated_at", "2014-07-14 12:02:49.949408"]]
   (1.1ms)  rollback transaction
NoMethodError: undefined method `current_user' for nil:NilClass
```

I appreciate any assistance anyone can provide. Thanks in advance.

Task model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  validates :description, presence: true

  default_scope { order('importance DESC', 'priority DESC', 'duedate','updated_at') }

  include PublicActivity::Model
  tracked owner: Proc.new{ |controller, model| controller.current_user }
end
```

Comment: Please post the code for your Task model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://github.com/pokonski/public_activity#disable-tracking-for-a-class-or-globally) for the public_activity gem you can disable the tracking using this command:

`PublicActivity.enabled = false`

If you run that command after starting the console you should be able to interact with the models without public_activity interfering.